# Exclude System.Diagnostics.Contracts When Using PartCover

Tags: .net, code-contracts, partcover

I am trying out the .net Code Contracts fro .net 3.5
I have some unit test that I am running PartCover over to calculate the code coverage.

PartCover keeps including the System.Diagnostics.Contracts in my report.
Here are the rules I am using to include MyProject and exclude everything else.

```
  <Rule>+[MyProject.DomainModel]*</Rule>
  <Rule>-[System]*</Rule>
  <Rule>-[System.Diagnostics]*</Rule>
  <Rule>-[System.Diagnostics.Contracts]*</Rule>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

PartCover's rule syntax is `[assemblyname]namespace`, the contracts come from the Microsoft.Contracts assembly and therefore the configuration has to look like this:

```
<Rule>+[MyProject.DomainModel]*</Rule>
<Rule>-[Microsoft.Contracts]*</Rule>
```

Read the PartCover Console Manual that is installed with PartCover for more details.